# Can this be triangulated?

Tags: recreational-mathematics, triangulation

Given N people with their phones that can sense the signal strength of every other phone knowing what phone it is. Phones don't know their absolute location (underground). There is a formula that gives a distance for a signal strength. Also these phones can talk to each other without limitation. Is it possible to triangulate the spatial disposition of each phone (an angle and distance to each of them). If so, how?

Comment: The question needs to be made more precise. Does every phone know its own location, and if so, what prevents it from simply communicating that location to all the others?

Comment: No. Phone doesn't know it's location.

Comment: Then it is not clear what you mean by spatial disposition. No translation or rotation would alter signal strengths.

Comment: Angle and distance to each phone.

Comment: Are the phones distributed in two dimensions or three?

Comment: 2 dimensions please

Answer (score 4):

Angles are hopeless because any rotation of the plane preserves the strength of every received signal. Similarly for an inversion (mirror image). Apart from that, however, relative positions and angles are determined because every triangle is determined up to isometry by the lengths of it sides and therefore every polygon is determined up to isometry by the lengths of its sides plus diagonals, by dividing it into triangles in various ways.

Comment: If you know the distances between every pair of three phones, then you get the angles from the law of cosines. So angles are not "hopeless" if you do that.  Later you say "relative positions and angles are determined", seemingly contradicting your earlier assertion that "angles are hopless".

Comment: Relative angles can be determined, as opposed to absolute orientations (like north and south).

Comment: Since when does "angles" mean "absolute orientations (like north and south)"? ${}\qquad{}$

Comment: Minor remark, if you know the distance to just two other phones, you have [this situation](http://jwilson.coe.uga.edu/EMAT6680Fa06/Sexton/Assignment%206/Tangents%20to%20Circles_files/image013.png), so there are two possibilities for the relative position (the points where the circles intersect).

Comment: @Michael The original question used angles in that sense, by suggesting that an angle and a distance (as in polar coordinates) determine a position.

Comment: @Ruben If there are only 3 phones then those two solutions are isometric - see my remark about the mirror image.

Comment: With multiple phones you have more data than you need to find the relative position of each phone up to mirror image.  You can do a fit to take out some of the noise in the data.

Comment: @Justpassingby I didn't even think of the general case, but you're right, this is always the case if you don't know the positions of the other phones.

Answer (score 2):

This is an optimization problem, in which all people need to be positioned such that they are properly distanced from everyone else.  Because you don't know their orientation, any "positioning" will have to be relative either to everyone else or to an arbitrary anchor.

I suggest you take a look at force directed drawing algorithms, which should solve your problem, which will give you the best solution when some data is noisy, or not all distances between phones are known, etc.

But from a  theoretical standpoint, simple trigonometry should do the trick. You'd have to repeat it for every phone knowing its distance to three "anchor phones" in which phone to phone distance is unnecessary. Note- distance to **three** anchor phones and not **two** because there is only one intersection of three circles (where 'r1!=r2') but two intersections for two circles.